# Jackson JSON Date Deserialization to Timestamp

Tags: java, date, serialization, jackson2

I am trying to map a JSON to POJO using Jackson2 for my REST method. The DueDate attribute in my POJO is of type java.util.date. 
I read that Jackson will deserialize JSON to timestamp by default. I want this behavior only. However, Jackson is converting the dueDate attribute to Date in my case.

Could anyone help me how to make Jackson deserialize the **dueDate as timestamp**.

JSON here ...

{
    "atr1": null,
    "atr2": null,
    "dueDate": "2018-07-11"
  }

POJO here ..

```
public class Sample {
    private String atr1;
    private String atr1;
    private Date dueDate;
}
```

REST Api ...

```
    public Response create(String json) {                                        
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Sample sample1 = mapper.readValue(json,Sample.class);
 }
```

Thanks

More details... the value type of DueDate when the method is called from the actual UI object is **Timestamp**

object [image]

However, when the JSON is passed to REST for the method call, the type changes to **Date**.
[image]

I want it to be **Timestamp** type. Because of this the SQL query which uses the dueDate as parameter doesn't fetch value properly.

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp? And how is it getting deserialized now?

Comment: @curlyBraces I have updated the description..Hope it makes my question more clear !

Comment: @BB8 `@JsonFormat` will solve your need

Comment: If you want the value to be `Timestamp`, declare the field as `Timestamp`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the POJO as my team does not have ownership over the code. We just control the REST methods. Thanks for your suggestions though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.sql.timestamp` in your pojo instead of `java.util.Date`.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class sample {
    private String atr1;
    private String atr2;
    private Timestamp dueDate;
}
```

You can access date timestamp with the same as you are doing above. I have also make code snippet for confirmation as below.

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        String json = "{ \"atr1\": null, \"atr2\": null, \"dueDate\": \"2018-07-11\" }";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        sample sample1 = mapper.readValue(json, sample.class);
        System.out.println(sample1.getDueDate());
    }
```

output of above:- `2018-07-11 05:30:00.0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use @JsonFormat for change the json date pattern like this:

```
public class Sample {
    private String atr1;
    private String atr1;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
    private Date dueDate;
}
```

For more information read this link:

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it doesn't help me with the type of the value ! Still the problem is not resolved

Comment: What is your framework? Can i see the rest of your code? For example you can use SimpleDateFormat to change the date format. It depends on your code and version of your frameworks